# Reactjs - Replacing array value from another

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I have an array of

```
var imagesArray = [
  {
   url: '4.jpg'
  },
  {
   url: '2.jpg'
  },
  {
   url: '3.jpg'
  }
];
```

And I got a JSON response of

```
   [{"path":"site:1.jpg","data":[]},
   {"path":"site:5.jpg","data":[]},
   {"path":"site:7.jpg","data":[]}]
```

How can I replace the `url` value in `imagesArray` from JSON response's `path` value as 1.jpg, 5.jpg, 7.jpg?

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is clear. What is the relationship? Their position in the array? Ie: does imagesArray[0] == response[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imagesArray = [
  {
   url: '4.jpg'
  },
  {
   url: '2.jpg'
  },
  {
   url: '3.jpg'
  }
];

response =    [{"path":"site:1.jpg","data":[]},
   {"path":"site:5.jpg","data":[]},
   {"path":"site:7.jpg","data":[]}]

class Test extends React.Component {
        render(){
    imagesArray = imagesArray.map((img,i)=>{return({url : response[i].path}) })
        return (
        <code>{JSON.stringify(imagesArray)}</code>
      )
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1583/)

Comment: I need a output as [{"url":"1.jpg"},{"url":"5.jpg"},{"url":"7.jpg"}]

Comment: How can I add if `response` > `imagesArray`

Answer (score 2):

This will give you an array of three objects with the url property you want.

```
var formatedResponse = response.map((r) => { return {url: r.path.split(':')[1]};})
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this :

```js
let imagesArray = [
  {
    url: '4.jpg'
  },
  {
    url: '2.jpg'
  },
  {
    url: '3.jpg'
  }
];
    
let response = [
  {"path":"site:1.jpg","data":[]},
  {"path":"site:5.jpg","data":[]},
  {"path":"site:7.jpg","data":[]}
]

let newArray = imagesArray.map( (img, i) => img.url = response.filter( r => r.path)[i]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

[Here is fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1582/)